# Press [right-click] -> delete

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

**1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

The tag doesn't really add something to the understanding of the question. It simply describes a user action, regardless of the used technology or nearly any technical detail.

Therefore, it may be used to describe different topics on different contexts.

**2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

It can be, but may not. The tag may be used for programming questions, but is more likely used for questions which ask about something what happened in a program because of a right click, which is in almost every case not really programming related.

**3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

Not really, as the [right-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/right-click) action will usually be described in the question itself and is in most cases only a minor detail.

It also does not describe some fundamental information about the question.

**4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

No, as the [right-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/right-click) may be used in different contexts with different outputs.

Comment: "*but is more likely used for questions which ask about something what happened in a program because of a right click*" well, is it? Because just *guessing* is not good enough. Or have you investigated and reached this conclusion?

Comment: @VLAZ Questions that may prove this point [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70785124/what-happened-to-google-chrome-devtools-extension-context-menu-right-click) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73036164/vscode-interesting-undocumented-feature) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73036164/vscode-interesting-undocumented-feature) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72304264/i-got-undefined-row-data-when-i-click-on-jquery-datatable) [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72163597/how-to-remove-items-from-right-click-context-menu-in-visual-studio-code).

Answer (score -3):

I disagree with burnination.

> It simply describes a user action, regardless of the used technology or nearly any technical detail.

The same could be said for [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/click) (9186 questions), which would be understood normally as the left click.  I think having a separate tag for a separate clicking action is good.

[double-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/double-click) (848 questions) is also a user action (or two actions if you like) as is a [long-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/long-click).

Do you think [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/click) ,[double-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/double-click), and [long-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/long-click) should also be burninated?  Your reasoning applies equally to these.

> 2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?
>
> It can be, but may not. The tag may be used for programming questions, but is more likely used for questions which ask about something what happened in a program because of a right click, which is in almost every case not really programming related.

I disagree with your opinion that "something that happened in a program because of a right click" is not programming related.  What happens in a program as a reaction to user input is because that program was programmed by someone.  Can you cite a case where something happens in a program because of a right click, that was not the result of someone programming it?

> 4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?
>
> No, as the right-click may be used in different contexts with different outputs.

I don't think [right-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/right-click) means anything other than user input using a mouse and clicking the secondary mouse button (on the right by default).  Different contexts react differently to that action, but the action is unambiguous.

Comment: "The same could be said for click" that another bad tag exist, shouldn't be used as defense that the current bad tag exist, unless the same reason to keeping them can be applied to both. Example of this is [sony]. Sony as a tag is an exception to "no company tags". You don't offer a similar argument on your answer. Also, right clicking depends on the context and therefore ambiguous, isn't that what ambiguous means?

Comment: "Do you think click ,double-click, and long-click should also be burninated?" Sadly, the current intransigent interpretation is that you get one tag per post, so if the user believed that the same argument applies to several tags, it can't be argued in the same post, so this point is moot.

Comment: @Braiam feel free to submit a request for `[click]`, and feel free to [actually participate in its burnination if you feel strongly about it](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/user/792066).

Comment: Well, I maybe do not participate in burninations because it's a waste of my time, when we should just remove them all from the database and start from zero and a short list of 1k tags. Also, because every-time I try to get suspended too. So, not much motivation from SO.